# PietCreator C++ won't compile

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake

I'm trying to compile PietCreator using CMake, but I get various error codes. How can I fix this?

Error codes:

```
 Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c"failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
The system can not find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
The system can not find the file specified
```

Here is source: https://github.com/Ramblurr/PietCreator

Compiling with CMake 3.3.0 and Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64 on Windows 8.1 64x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building project files with CMake, you have to make sure to install all dependencies and (usually) use the compiler suggested in the docs of whatever source code you are building project files for. In this case, you'll need Qt 4.x installed, along with the Visual C++ 2008 compiler. After doing that, you should be able to tell CMake to use that version compiler, set the QT 4.x directory in the main window of the GUI (or by command line), and have your .sln file created.

Comment: How would I set up qt? You mean I install in build directory?

Comment: No, I mean install QT just like you would to start developing with it. I found you the link [here](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.6/).